# proguard is not preserving annotations

Tags: android, gradle

I've been using the "[UI form validation library for Android](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)" library for validating my user interfaces. And I've also implemented some custom validation rules for example:

```
public class CellRule extends AnnotationRule<Cell, String> {
    protected CellRule(Cell cell) {
        super(cell);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String text) {
        if(text.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        String cellNumber = StringUtils.toStandard(text);

        Pattern cellPattern = Pattern.compile("^(0|\\+98)9(1[0-9]|3[1-9]|2[1-9])-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$");
        Matcher cellMatcher = cellPattern.matcher(cellNumber);

        return cellMatcher.matches();
    }
}

@ValidateUsing(CellRule.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Cell {
    int sequence()          default -1;
    int messageResId()      default -1;
    String message()        default "Invalid Cell!";
}
```

and I registered them using this command:

```
Validator.registerAnnotation(Cell.class);
```

and it's been working as expected. Until I tried to generate signed apk (with minification enabled) and now it gives me some errors...when I checked the apk out (using decompilation) it seems that proguard is not preserving annotations (`@interface Cell`) in the apk.

when I commented out the registration line all is good.

Answer (score 0):

I found that every library has it's own progaurd settings and it's probably documented in the README file of the library!

for saripaar's library this would do the trick:

```
-keep class com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.** {*;}
-keep @com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.ValidateUsing class * {*;}
```